# Message is being rejected for incompatible schema

Tags: java, apache-kafka, jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to send the message to a Kafka topic with schema. Seems like the message matches with schema but message is being rejected with following error.

**code**

```java
   String topic = "gcp.test_schema";
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream inputStream = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("src/main/resources/client.properties"));
        props.load(inputStream);
        // Create Kafka producer
        Producer<String, Object> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

        String jsonPayload = "{\"age\": \"30\"}";

        // Create a Kafka record with JSON payload
        ProducerRecord<String, Object> kafkaRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, jsonPayload);

        // Send the record to Kafka topic
        producer.send(kafkaRecord, (metadata, exception) -> {
            if (exception != null) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Message sent successfully!");
                System.out.println("Partition: " + metadata.partition());
                System.out.println("Offset: " + metadata.offset());
            }
        });

    }
```

**topic details**

```
❯ ./bin/confluent kafka topic describe gcp.test_schema
                   Name                   |                          Value                           | Read-Only
------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+------------
  cleanup.policy                          | delete                                                   | false
  compression.type                        | producer                                                 | true
  confluent.key.schema.validation         | false                                                    | false
  confluent.key.subject.name.strategy     | io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy | false
  confluent.value.schema.validation       | false                                                    | false
  confluent.value.subject.name.strategy   | io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy | false
```

**Topic Schema**

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "age": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

**property file**

```
# Required connection configs for Kafka producer, consumer, and admin
bootstrap.servers=xxx.northamerica-northeast1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='xxx' password='xxx/iQEXntX/xx';
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

value.serializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer
confluent.value.schema.validation=true

# Required connection configs for Confluent Cloud Schema Registry
schema.registry.url=https://qqqq.us-east1.gcp.confluent.cloud
basic.auth.credentials.source=USER_INFO
basic.auth.user.info=ffff:ssd+ddd+YySi
```

**Error**

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject "gcp.test_schema-value", 
details: [{errorType:"TYPE_CHANGED", description:"A type at path '#/' is different between the new schema and the old schema'}, {oldSchemaVersion: 1}, {oldSchema: '{"properties":{"age":{"type":"string"}}}'}, {compatibility: 'BACKWARD'}]; error code: 409; error code: 409
```

**Update**

**Tried with Map**

```java
Producer<String, Map> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, Map>(props);
ProducerRecord<String, Map> kafkaRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, Map.of("age", "30"));
```

**Error**: ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES_NARROWED

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject "gcp.test_schema-value", 
details: [{errorType:"ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES_NARROWED", description:"An array or combined type at path '#/additionalProperties' has fewer elements in the new schema than the old schema'}, {oldSchemaVersion: 1}, {oldSchema: '{"properties":{"age":{"type":"string"}}}'}, {compatibility: 'BACKWARD'}]; error code: 409
```

**Update 2 - With class**

```java
class User {
    @JsonProperty
    public String age;
    public User() {}
    public User(String age) {
        this(age, null);
    }
    public User(String age, Object o) {
    }
}


Producer<String, User> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, User>(props);
User user = new User("30");
ProducerRecord<String, User> kafkaRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, user);
```

Error - ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES_REMOVED

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidConfigurationException: Schema being registered is incompatible with an earlier schema for subject "gcp.test_schema-value", 
details: [{errorType:"ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES_REMOVED", description:"The keyword at path '#/additionalProperties' in the new schema is not present in the old schema'}, {oldSchemaVersion: 1}, {oldSchema: '{"properties":{"age":{"type":"string"}}}'}, {compatibility: 'BACKWARD'}]; error code: 409; error code: 409
```

**Update 3:**

I tried changing my schema to following

```json
{
  "$id": "http://example.com/myURI.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "description": "Sample schema to help you get started.",
  "properties": {
    "age": {
      "description": "The string type is used for strings of text.",
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "title": "SampleRecord",
  "type": "object"
}
```

Now this doesn't give me any error, but depends on what I use, either class or map, the schema gets a new version. The message never delivers to the topic, neither I get any error.

I see following version after I use map

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "additionalProperties": {},
  "title": "Map 1",
  "type": "object"
}
```

Comment: 1) Please show your property file, we don't know what serializer you're using 2) You probably shouldn't use `Object` for JSONSchema. Use [a custom class](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/json-schema-serializer/src/test/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/json/KafkaJsonSchemaSerializerTest.java#L188) or a Map, which both need `age` fields/keys, not `myField1`

Comment: The schema has the attribute 'age' and the code 'myField1'. They are not the same.

Comment: @OneCricketeer `myField1` was a typo.

Comment: Okay. What happens when you don't use Object class as your value?

Comment: @OneCricketeer what should I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a String that's been type erased to an Object.

It has no "schema" other than "string" (no age field)

You need to define the Producer with, and send, a Map or class *with fields* that represents your schema (there's a [jsonschema2pojo maven plugin](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/wiki/Getting-Started) that can create such classes)

You can find examples in the unit tests for the json schema serializer

https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/json-schema-serializer/src/test/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/json/KafkaJsonSchemaSerializerTest.java

Sidenote: age should probably be a number, rather than a string

Comment: I tried with Map, and getting a different error.

Comment: Your errors are related to the "old schema". Issue a delete request to the registry for the subject `gcp.test_schema-value`. The producer automatically registers a schema, so you didn't need to pre-create one directly in the registry.. Otherwise, as mentioned, download the existing schema in the registry and use the linked maven plugin to create your class, not define one manually. Here is a useful blog about how JSON compatibility works - https://yokota.blog/2021/03/29/understanding-json-schema-compatibility/

Comment: Actually, your last update is correct. You are missing `producer.flush()` usage since the send() does not make an immediate network call

Comment: it worked, after flush(). so do I have to create `POJO` for my json ? I am getting this events from `dynamodb` as string.

Comment: isn't there any way I can send either a JSON string or convert JSON to map and send it ?

Comment: Sure. Don't use the schema registry. Use StringSerializer for the value. Not sure how dynamo is related to the problem. You can still parse string payloads into POJO classes using `ObjectMapper.readTree`

Comment: can I send `Map` instead of serializing object using Java Library and sending pojo. I tried that and now it's accepting everything. even things which doesn't match with schema.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, yes, a map could be used, but it will be a "map schema" since values in a map cannot be different types... If it's accepting anything, sounds like you're no longer using a serializer that's provided by Confluent